# Unable to parse package.json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

i'm trying to upload a javascript nodejs project to Heroku.
Localhost works perfectly but when i try to upload it gives me a unable to parse error at :

```
...
"engines" : { "node" : ">0.11.9" },
...
```

The Error Message : Invalid numeric literal at line 12, column 0

Full JSON File:

```
{
  "name": "browsergameprojecz",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongojs": "^2.6.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "engines" : { "node" : ">0.11.9" },

  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: You may need to specify a concrete engine version. Try, say, `{"node": "10.8.0"}`?

Comment: no that makes no diffrence. Same erorr even with .x at the end. Everything should work so ...

Answer (score 1):

there are Linters for that, eg. the [Package JSON Validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/package-json-validator)

... which lets one inspect the validity of such JSON files.

besides [Node 0.11.9](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v0.11.9/) is roughly 5 years old and tagged as `unstable`

... consider upgrading, while this is possible in combination with the rest.

there might be Windows line-ending in that file ...as it often is the case, when "everything looks fine", but still not works are excepted. dos2unix can be used to fix them.

https://techblog.dorogin.com/writing-cross-platform-npm-scripts-on-windows-79c510339ea6 hints for, that when files have a `UTF-8 BOM` `0x EF BB BF` at the beginning, this also makes it un-parse-able. unless checking this with a hex-editor, one can not know. simply creating a new `package.json` with `UTF-8` endoding and UNIX `\n` line-endings should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is from the official npm docs. It looks like you need a range for a version not just a lower limit. Or an approximate version. However from my experience with Heroku I have never needed this it seems heroku will probably use a node version much higher. Also if you need a specific version there is such a thing called `engineStrict` which you can have a look at in the official npm docs.

Comment: Okay even when i try to change the version number to a specific or a range it gives me the same erorr... The EngineStrict thing is not avaible anymore since version 3.0.0

Comment: Have you tried removing it? Maybe heroku doesn't have "engines" in their package.json.. Like it might not even exist? Every nodejs project I have uploaded to heroku has worked fine. However I do mostly use the most recent versions of node and not ones that are ~5 years old!

Answer (score 0):

When the data is upload to the client from the server side in JSON format, some special characters can not be displayed directly when the JS is displayed on the HTML page. As the background is passed through the `<b>msg</b>`, it is displayed in the HTML page `msg` by JS, and it is not **`msg`**. This is due to the content between `<` and `>` as HTML. Tagging, and start with HTML as entity, so the display is not normal.
The solution is simple, and can be rendered before JS is rendered to HTML pages.

Comment: we are not talking about client-side JavaScript, which would run inside a browser ...